# Opencv video frame giving me an error

Tags: c++, image-processing, opencv

Trying to perform grayscale transformation on frames on a video ,but keep getting Assertation failed error when I get to cvCvtColor.
Does anyone see where my error is?

```
    IplImage *frame, *frame_copy = 0;

// capture frames from video
CvCapture *capture = cvCaptureFromFile( "lightinbox1.avi");
//Allows Access to video propertys
cvQueryFrame(capture);

//Get the number of frames
int nframe=(int) cvGetCaptureProperty(capture,CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT);

    //Name window
cvNamedWindow( "video:", 1 );

    //start loop
for(int i=0;i<nframe;i++){
//prepare capture frame extraction
cvGrabFrame(capture);
cout<<"We are on frame "<<i<<"\n";
//Get this frame
frame = cvRetrieveFrame( capture );
con2txt(frame);
    frame_copy = cvCreateImage(cvSize(frame->width,frame->height),IPL_DEPTH_8U,frame->nChannels );
//show and destroy frame
    cvCvtColor( frame,frame,CV_RGB2GRAY);

cvShowImage("video:",frame);
cvWaitKey(33);}
cvReleaseCapture(&capture);
```

}

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually, the problem is that `cvCvtColor()` with `CV_RGB2GRAY` expects an output image with `nChannels == 1`.

To solve the issue, you must adjust your copy procedure to:

```
frame_copy = cvCreateImage(cvSize(frame->width,frame->height), IPL_DEPTH_8U, 1);
cvCvtColor(frame, frame_copy, CV_RGB2GRAY);
```

Comment: Thats great, but why when I add                                   frame_copy1 = cvCreateImage(cvSize(frame->width,frame->height),IPL_DEPTH_16S,1 );     cvSobel(frame_copy,frame_copy1,2,2,3); cvShowImage("video:",frame_copy1);                                   Does it show me a blank screen

Comment: That is another question, I suggest you ask it in a new thread. But I suspect it has to do with the depth of the images, the resulting image is being stored on `IPL_DEPTH_16S` but the original probably is `IPL_DEPTH_8U`.

Answer (score 2):

You're calling `cvCvtColor` with the same frame as source and destination image.

This isn't possible, since `cvCvtColor` must change the number of channels in the image in order to convert rgb to grey.

Call `cvtColor` with a new image as the destination, instead.