# Opencv video frame not showing Sobel output

Tags: c++, image-processing, opencv

This is a continuation question from
[Opencv video frame giving me an error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8243378/opencv-video-frame-giving-me-an-error)
I think I closed it off, Im new to Stackoverflow.

I have code below that Im trying to see its Sobel edge image. However the program runs but the output is just a grey screen where if I mouseover the cursor disappears.
Does anyone see the error? or is it a misunderstanding about the data structures Im using

```
IplImage *frame, *frame_copy = 0;

// capture frames from video
CvCapture *capture = cvCaptureFromFile( "lightinbox1.avi");
//Allows Access to video propertys
cvQueryFrame(capture);

//Get the number of frames
int nframe=(int) cvGetCaptureProperty(capture,CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT);

//Name window
cvNamedWindow( "video:", 1 );

//start loop
for(int i=0;i<nframe;i++){
//prepare capture frame extraction
cvGrabFrame(capture);
cout<<"We are on frame "<<i<<"\n";
//Get this frame
frame = cvRetrieveFrame( capture );
con2txt(frame);
frame_copy = cvCreateImage(cvSize(frame->width,frame->height),IPL_DEPTH_8U,frame->nChannels );
//show and destroy frame
cvCvtColor( frame,frame,CV_RGB2GRAY);

 //Create Sobel output
 frame_copy1 = cvCreateImage(cvSize(frame->width,frame->height),IPL_DEPTH_16S,1 );
cvSobel(frame_copy,frame_copy1,2,2,3);

cvShowImage("video:",frame_copy1);
cvWaitKey(33);}
cvReleaseCapture(&capture);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, I think it's because you are creating a destination image with different **depth** than the original:

```
frame_copy1 = cvCreateImage(cvSize(frame->width,frame->height),IPL_DEPTH_16S,1 );
```

and you should be doing:

```
frame_copy1 = cvCreateImage(cvSize(frame->width,frame->height),IPL_DEPTH_8U,1 );
```

Anyway, [this post](http://pirunga.wordpress.com/2009/04/06/introducao-opencv/) shows an example that uses `cvSobel`.

Comment: I think he's using the correct depths.  `cvSobel` expects the output type to be `IPL_DEPTH_16S` if the input is `IPL_DEPTH_8U` because the result of Sobel filtering may be negative.

Answer (score 1):

I think OpenCV is having problems intelligently displaying your 16 bit image.  You can verify whether or not this is the case by performing the following steps:

1. Create an 8 bit image (call it `result8bit`).  OpenCV is good at displaying these.
2. Calculate the minimum and maximum of `frame_copy1` (see `cvMinMaxLoc`)
3. Use `cvScale` to convert `frame_copy1` to `result8bit` using the minimum and maximum to scale the image
4. Show `result8bit`.

Good luck.